# Unable to view geometry in ARKit Scene after loading in from .scn file

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I have a `swatch.scn` file and I'm trying to add its geometry to my `scene`. I have to grab `swatch.childNodes.first` to get the proper geometry and then I add it but nothing shows up in my `scene`. Would love any thoughts on how to solve this. Thanks!

```
extension SCNNode {

    convenience init(named name: String) {
        self.init()
        guard let scene = SCNScene(named: name) else { return }

        for childNode in scene.rootNode.childNodes {
            addChildNode(childNode)
        }
    }

}


// in viewDidLoad

// Create a new scene
let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/ship.scn")!

let swatch = SCNNode(named: "art.scnassets/swatch.scn")
let n = swatch.childNodes.first!
let geo = n.geometry!
print(n.geometry!) // <SCNGeometry: 0x281cb3b60 'bigger_swatch'>
n.position = SCNVector3(0, 0, -1)
n.scale = SCNVector3(3, 3, 3)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
let swatch = SCNNode(named: "art.scnassets/swatch.scn")
swatch.position = SCNVector3(0, 0, -1)
swatch.scale = SCNVector3(3, 3, 3)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(swatch)

// Note: your swatch-node holds the entire geometries from your file.
// You can do something like this:
print(swatch.childnodes.count)
```